# SCSS Grid: more columns in row then maximum margin issue

Tags: html, css, grid, sass

I have an own made grid system wich supports up to `12`colums. But i can change that in these variables:

```
$column-count: 12;
$row-max-width: 1024px;

$gutter-width-px: 10px !default;
$gutter-width-procent: percentage($gutter-width-px / $row-max-width);
```

This is how the sizes are calculated:

```
@function calculate-one-column() {
  $a: 100%;
  @if ($gutter-width-px > 0px) {
    $a: ($a - ($gutter-width-procent * ($column-count - 1)));
  }
  @return $a / $column-count;
}

@function calculate-each-gutter() {
  @if ($gutter-width-px > 0px) {
    @return $gutter-width-procent;
  }
  @return 0;
}

@function calculate-function($function, $size, $first-child: false, $responsive: false) {
  $each-column: calculate-one-column() * $size;
  $each-gutter: calculate-each-gutter() * ($size - 1);
  @if ($function == 'size') {
    @return $each-column + $each-gutter;

  } @else if ($function == 'offset' and $first-child == false) and ($responsive == false) {
    @return $each-column + $each-gutter + ($gutter-width-procent * 1.5);

  } @else if ($function == 'push' or $function == 'pull') and ($responsive == false) or ($function == 'offset' and $first-child == true) {
    @return $each-column + $each-gutter + $gutter-width-procent;

  } @else if($function == 'offset' or 'push' or 'pull') and ($responsive == true)  {
    @return auto !important;
  }
}

@mixin make-grid-sizes() {
  @for $index from 1 through $column-count {
    &.#{$column-size}-#{$index} {
      width: calculate-function('size', $index);
    }
  }
}
```

The HTML markup for a row with `12` columns in it  of `size-1` looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
    <div class="column size-1">...</div>
</div>
```

Ofcourse, i can do this aswell:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column size-2">...</div>
    <div class="column size-2">...</div>
    <div class="column size-2">...</div>
    <div class="column size-2">...</div>
    <div class="column size-2">...</div>
    <div class="column size-2">...</div>
</div>
```

Or other combinations.

First, it looks like this (12 columns of `size-1`, this is 1 row):

[image: Row with margins:0 on sides]

I had to give the `:first-child` a `margin-left` of `0`, and the `:last-child` a `margin-right` of `0`.

This is because every `column` has a `margin` on every side of the `$gutter-width-procent / 2`:

```
margin: 0 #{$gutter-width-procent / 2};
```

Then it looks like this (this is 1 row):

[image]

This is working perfect, but now you are limited by putting just `12` columns in 1 row.

---

Now when i add for example `24` columns of `size-1` in a row, it looks like this (still the same `row`):

[image: Row with 24 columns in it]

I was able to fix this by adding these CSS rules to it:

(each last column a `margin-right` of `0` and each first column a `margin-left` of `0`)

```
&:first-child,
&:nth-of-type(#{$column-count}n + 1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}

&:last-child,
&:nth-of-type(#{$column-count}n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

But that only worked for a `column size-1`.

**Question**

How can I make it so that every first column in a 'row' in a `row` HTML elementhas a `margin-left` `0`.

And the same for the last column, but then a `margin-right` of `0`.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/DrVdS/2/)

Comment: have you checked the source code of [foundation](https://github.com/zurb/foundation)'s grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to add negative margins to `.row`:

```
.row {
  margin: 0 -#{$gutter-width-procent / 2};
}
```

Then you can remove all the `&:first/last/nth-child`-selectors as the col gutters will just "slip" into the negative margin space.

[Updated JS-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrVdS/4/)

I had to change the width values (didn't change all) to account for the added width caused by the negative margins. A bit unfamiliar for me since I use [Susy](http://susy.oddbird.net/) which takes care of all that for me. But you need to change the function for calculating widths somewhat. This is how I did the calculation:

```
$column-count: 12;
$row-max-width: 1024px;

$gutter-width-px: 10px !default;

@function col($cols: 1) {
  $row-width-neg-margin-width: $row-max-width + $gutter-width-px;
  @return ( ( $row-width-neg-margin-width / ($column-count / $cols) ) - $gutter-width-px ) / $row-width-neg-margin-width * 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you show that in a demo because it wont work for me for some reason.

Comment: thanks man, but how does it come i can scroll horizontally now? It does fix the problem, but except that?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. The scrollbars appear because the `.row` is wider than the `html`. It could be solved by adding another wrapper around `.row` with `overflow: hidden;` or as I did in the updated fiddle: added padding to `body`. You usually want some gutter around the grid anyways.

Comment: I see, thanks. But is'nt is possible to make the row the full `100%`, so without the outer padding. Without making another wrapper around the `.row` element? Because that was my whole point making the grid full width

Comment: I don't think you can get around some kind of wrapper with `overflow: hidden;` whether you place it on the `html` (which I wouldn't really reccomend) or on another element like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DrVdS/6/).

Comment: Ah okay, thanks man :). This answered my question indeed. But isnt there another way to do this? Without having a parent element and without setting `overflow: hidden`?